# How many events will be fired if we insert data into Dynamo DB table in the form of batches?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-batch

Batch job inserts data into Dynamo DB table 'T' in the form of batches of size 500 and there is one trigger on table 'T', Will DynamoDB fire event for each of the 500 records separately or single event for the entire batch?

Answer (score 1):

First off, DDB batches can contain a max of [25 items](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html), not 500.

> A single call to BatchWriteItem can write up to 16 MB of data, which
> can comprise as many as 25 put or delete requests.

But yes, each item would be delivered to your lambda via streams as an individual event.